# How can I debug a Windows build using Goland running on a Mac?

Tags: windows, goland

I have noticed some issues that happen only on Windows build. However, I develop on Golang running on Mac. How can I debug the Windows build using Goland running on a Mac?

Comment: Please, provide a bit more details. You cannot debug Windows binary on macOS for sure without remote debugging. What issues are you facing?

Comment: I figured. We can change the build tags in Goland to Windows. Please see the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer of how to debug for Windows while developing on Mac. We need to change the target OS in Goland.

Go to *Preferences → Go → Build Tags & Vendoring* and choose OS to Windows.

[image: Choose Build tags in Goland]